# How to produce interreflections in Unity3d?

Tags: unity, reflection-rendering

Notice how the "door" shown below appears multiple times in the reflections, both vertically and horizontally. These "extra" reflections are called interreflections. I am trying to reproduce this effect in Unity3d.

[image]

There are [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AdvancedRefProbe.html) for interreflections, but following the provided steps does not produce any additional reflections. I spoke to a few others who also had a similar problem--it seems that increasing the bounce count alone does not produce interreflections.

So how can I do it? What are the additional steps required to do this? Is this effect not called an interreflection? If so, what is it, and how can I produce it?

Comment: The particular example you show might be easier to recreate using screenspace reflections (SSR). Have you experimented with that?